# Which USA Brokerage Firms can I transfer my India stocks to?

Tags: united-states, stocks, india, broker

I would like to know which US brokerage firms I can transfer my India stocks to, after finding out my current brokerage (TD Ameritratde) requires doing so...

Comment: Why did they tell you to transfer?

Comment: Please note that requests for specific service provider recommendations are now off-topic. (They might not have been when the question was originally asked.) Voting to close now.

Answer (score 0):

You might what to check out Interactive Brokers. If your India stock is NSE listed they might be able to do it since they support trading on that exchange. I would talk to a customer service rep there first.

https://www.interactivebrokers.com/en/index.php?f=exchanges&p=asia